# Is there a possibility to pack a svn checkout from read-only repository?

Tags: git, svn

`svnadmin pack` can be used to convert a large number of small files on the server repository into larger one in order to decrease I/O overhead. If I checked out a read-only repository (i.e. a repository to which I don't have administration and write permissions) do I have any chance to do such optimization on the client (in git I would issues `git gc`?

Comment: What's your reasoning behind doing so? What are you attempting to accomplish? Subversion doesn't work anywhere near the same as git, so trying to find equivalent functions is usually not fruitful.

Comment: "decrease I/O overhead" (see above) when reading the source root folder (e.g. when moving the folder or making backups) which occurs when a lot of small files have to be read - there's a reason why `git gc` reduces the number of files. I guess it doesn't matter how subversion works as the problem is generic to all types of SCMs.

Comment: In the context of Subversion, the server & client storage schemas are completely different. The items packed by svnadmin pack exist in the server but are not present on the client working copy.